# Compare json arrays and result in a simple array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two JSONS and i have to create an array from it

Array1: `[{ label: "HEADER" value:"header" }, { label: "FOOTER" value:"footer" }]`

Array2: `[ { header: "Header 1", footer: "Footer 1" }, { header: "Header 2", footer: "Footer 2" }]`

Expected Array(The label of Array1 will be the search criteria from Array2 Keys : `[["Header 1","Header 2"],["Footer 1","Footer 2"]]`

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Array.map()` on Array1, then for each value in this array, run .map() again, returning all matching items in Array2.

We'd use `Array.find()` and `String.includes()` to do this.

```js
const Array1 = [ { label: "HEADER", value:"header" }, { label: "FOOTER", value:"footer" } ]  
const Array2 = [ { header: "Header 1", footer: "Footer 1" }, { header: "Header 2", footer: "Footer 2" } ]

const result = Array1.map(({ label, value}) => { 
    return Array2.map((obj) => { 
        let key = Object.keys(obj).find(key => key.includes(value));
        return key ? obj[key]: null;
    })
})
console.log('Result:', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another example, this time Array2 has an entry with no footer property (as requested):

```js
const Array1 = [ { label: "HEADER", value:"header" }, { label: "FOOTER", value:"footer" } ]  
const Array2 =  [ { header: "Header 1", footer: "Footer 1" }, { header: "Header 2" }]

const result = Array1.map(({ label, value}) => { 
    return Array2.map((obj) => { 
        let key = Object.keys(obj).find(key => key.includes(value));
        return key ? obj[key]: null;
    })
})
console.log('Result:', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: it seems to work but if Array2 has less data like this [ { header: "Header 1", footer: "Footer 1" }, { header: "Header 2" }] I wanted the result to be like[["Header 1","Header 2"],["Footer 1",null]] . Is that possible?

Comment: Sure, that's a small change. I've updated the answer and included a second snippet with that use case. Hope that help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking for granted that array1 values can only contain 'header' | 'footer' and that each array2 item has a header and a footer property since it's not specified. So it would be:

```js
const array1 = JSON.parse(/* JSON1 file content */);
const array2 = JSON.parse(/* JSON2 file content */);

const result = array1.map(item1 => {
    const criteria = item1.label.toLowerCase();
    return array2.map(item2 => item2[criteria]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let Array1=[{label:"HEADER",value:"header",},{label:"FOOTER",value:"footer",}] ,Array2=[{header:"Header 1",footer:"Footer 1"},{header:"Header 2",footer:"Footer 2"}]

let result = Array1.map(e => e.label.toLowerCase())
                   .map(s => Array2.map(n => n[s]))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple double `Array.map` will help.

**Logic**

- First `Array.map` will return the `value`s from first array `arr1`.
- Second `Array.map` will return elements from second array `arr2` with keys as value from `arr1`

```js
const arr1 = [{ label: "HEADER", value: "header" }, { label: "FOOTER", value: "footer" }]
const arr2 = [{ header: "Header 1", footer: "Footer 1" }, { header: "Header 2", footer: "Footer 2" }];
const output = arr1.map(item => arr2.map(node => node[item.value]));
console.log(output);
```